# Alarm on Java Clock

Tags: java, alarm

This is a homework assignment.

I am trying to create a java 12 hour clock with an alarm. After a week of constant work I finally have it running, however, when I set the alarm, it goes off 2-3 minutes before the set time. Also, when I hit snooze (which is supposed to snooze for 2 minutes) it immediately goes off the next minute. I have 10 classes total, but I am adding the ones that should be relevant `Time` and `TimeManager`. I am just beginning Java, and I am having a hard time with it, so sorry if this is a dumb question.

`Time`:

```
public class Time {
private int hour;
private int minute;

public Time(int initHour, int initMinute) {
    if (1 <= hour && hour <= 12) {
        hour = initHour;
    }
    else if (hour == 0) {
        hour = 12;
    }
    if (0 <= minute && minute <= 59 ) {
        minute = initMinute;
    }
}

public void addOneMinute() {
    minute++;
    if (minute == 59) {
        incrementHour();
        minute = 0;
    }
}

public void incrementHour() {
    hour++;
    if (hour > 12) {
        hour = 1;
    }
}

public void incrementMinute() {
    minute++; 
    if (minute == 59) {
        minute = 0;
    }
}

public int getHour() {
    if (hour >= 1 && hour <= 12) {
    }
    return hour;
}

public int getMinute() {
    if (minute >=0 && minute <= 59) {
    }
    return minute;
}

public boolean equals(Time time) {
    if (hour == hour && minute == minute) {     
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

`TimeManager`:

```
public class TimeManager {
private static final int SNOOZE_DURATION_IN_MINUTES = 2;
private Time currentTime;
private Time alarmTime;
private Time snoozeTime;
private Display     display;
private ModeManager modeMgr;
private Alarm       alarm;

public TimeManager() {
    currentTime = new Time(12,0);
    alarmTime = new Time(12,0);
    snoozeTime = new Time(12,0);
}

public void setDisplay(Display newDisplay) {
    display = newDisplay;
    showCurrentTime();
}

public void setModeManager(ModeManager newModeMgr) {
    modeMgr = newModeMgr;
}

public void setAlarm(Alarm newAlarm) {
    alarm = newAlarm;
}

    public void incrementCurrentMinute() {
    currentTime.addOneMinute();
    Mode mode = modeMgr.getMode();
    if (mode == mode.ALARM_ON || mode == mode.ALARM_OFF || mode == mode.SET_TIME) {
        updateDisplay();
    }
    if (mode == mode.ALARM_ON) {
        if (currentTime.equals(alarmTime) || currentTime.equals(snoozeTime)) {
        soundAlarmIfNecessary();
        }
    }
}

public void incrementCurrentHour() {
    currentTime.incrementHour();
    Mode mode = modeMgr.getMode();
    if (mode == mode.ALARM_ON || mode == mode.ALARM_OFF || mode == mode.SET_TIME) {
        updateDisplay();
    }
    if (mode == mode.ALARM_ON) {
        if (currentTime.equals(alarmTime) || currentTime.equals(snoozeTime)) {
        soundAlarmIfNecessary();
        }
    }
}

public void incrementAlarmMinute() {
    alarmTime.incrementMinute();
    Mode mode = modeMgr.getMode();
    if (mode == mode.SET_ALARM) {
        updateDisplay();
    }
    if (mode == mode.ALARM_ON) {
        if (currentTime.equals(alarmTime)) {
            soundAlarmIfNecessary();
        }
    }
}

public void incrementAlarmHour() {
    alarmTime.incrementHour();
    Mode mode = modeMgr.getMode();
    if (mode == mode.SET_ALARM) {
        updateDisplay();
    }
    if (mode == mode.ALARM_ON) {
        if (currentTime.equals(alarmTime)) {
            soundAlarmIfNecessary();
        }
    }
}

public void snooze() {
    while (alarm.isOn()) {
        alarm.off();
        int hour = currentTime.getHour();
        int minute = currentTime.getMinute();
        minute += SNOOZE_DURATION_IN_MINUTES;
            if (minute > 59) {
                minute -= 60;
                ++hour;
            }
        snoozeTime = new Time(hour, minute);
        }
}

public void showCurrentTime() {
    display.showHour(currentTime.getHour());
    display.showMinute(currentTime.getMinute());
}

public void showAlarmTime() {
    display.showHour(alarmTime.getHour());
    display.showMinute(alarmTime.getMinute());
}

private void updateDisplay() {
    Mode mode = modeMgr.getMode();
    if (mode == mode.SET_TIME || mode == mode.ALARM_ON || mode == mode.ALARM_OFF) {
        showCurrentTime();
    }
    else {
        showAlarmTime();
    }
}

private void soundAlarmIfNecessary() {
    Mode mode = modeMgr.getMode();
    if (mode == mode.ALARM_ON && currentTime.equals(alarmTime) || currentTime.equals(snoozeTime)) {
        alarm.on();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: in `Time.addOneMinute` consider incrementing `minute` after you check for 59.  otherwise you'll 'roll over' to 0 at 58, instead of 59.  Looks like the same error for all your increment/addOne methods in `Time`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't even realize that. Between you and @jazzbassrob it is working perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amoungst other things, you have quite a significant bug in the `Time.equals()` method:

```
public boolean equals(Time time) {

    if (hour == hour && minute == minute) {     
        return true;
        }
    else {
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The expression `hour == hour` is comparing the `hour` instance variable with itself, which will always be `true`.  This is clearly not what you want, instead you want to compare it with the `hour` field of the given `time` argument, like this:

```
    if (hour == time.getHour() && minute == time.getMinute() ) {
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. The professor gave us just the class and we were left from there to figure it out. I knew it was wrong but I wasn't sure what to do to fix it. This completely fix my issue and it works perfect now. You guys here are awesome! I hope I can become as versed as you all one day!